# MySQL query LEFT JOIN missing values

Tags: mysql

My query for some reason is leaving out the ISRC CODE of most of the values. The two records that do contain the ISRC CODE are the ones that show up because of the join. `$artist_name = "Brady Hartvigsen"` for these queries

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
        FROM isrc_codes i
        LEFT JOIN contributors c on i.ISRC_CODE = c.ISRC_CODE
        WHERE i.TRACK_ARTIST = '" . $artist_name . "' 
        OR c.CONTRIBUTOR = '" . $artist_name . "' 
        ORDER BY i.ISRC_CODE DESC");
```

Which gives me this output

ISRC CODE/Song/Artist/Contributor/Percentage

---

QMJND1400003    Let's Jump  Shane Bingham   Brady Hartvigsen (10%)  40%

---

QMJND1400002    Nowhere City of Kings   Brady Hartvigsen (50%)  0%

---

Scarlet Skies   Brady Hartvigsen        50%

---

Stranded    Brady Hartvigsen        50%

---

With this code I get output with the ISRC CODEs but not on tracks that the person is a contributor on

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
        FROM isrc_codes 
        WHERE TRACK_ARTIST = '" . $artist_name . "' 
        OR CONTRIBUTOR = '" . $artist_name . "' 
        ORDER BY ISRC_CODE DESC");
```

GBSMU1274772    Scarlet Skies   Brady Hartvigsen        50%

---

GBSMU1274771    Stranded    Brady Hartvigsen        50%

---

---

So what I would need would be this

QMJND1400003    Let's Jump  Shane Bingham   Brady Hartvigsen (10%)  40%

---

QMJND1400002    Nowhere City of Kings   Brady Hartvigsen (50%)  0%

---

GBSMU1274772    Scarlet Skies   Brady Hartvigsen        50%

---

GBSMU1274771    Stranded    Brady Hartvigsen        50%

ISRC Code Table
[image: ISRC Code Table]

Contributor Table

[image: Contributor Table]

For some reason it puts the ISRC CODE in `[0]` but not in `[ISRC_CODE]`

```
Array
(
    [0] => GBSMU1094901
    [ISRC_CODE] => 
    [1] => Take My Heart
    [TRACK_TITLE] => Take My Heart
    [2] => 
    [TRACK_SUBTITLE] => 
    [3] => Brady Hartvigsen
    [TRACK_ARTIST] => Brady Hartvigsen
    [4] => 50
    [CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE] => 50
    [5] => 
    [id] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [contributor] => 
    [8] => 
    [contributor_percentage] => 
)
```

Comment: AS per My Knowledge That must Filter with in Where Clause

Comment: Problem is not clear

Comment: It would really help to have some sample input data, desired output, and actual output. Also, seems to me the single & double quotes around $artist_name may not be as you want.

Comment: We need a clearer picture of your table structures.

Comment: what do you mean by clearer picture?